# How to initialize a 2d array with -1 globally?

Tags: c++, arrays

The below is the basic code. I want to make the array globally so that i don't have to call it for every function.Now how do I initialize the 2d array with -1. I tried to use **memset(arr,-1,sizeof(arr))** just below line 3, but it didn't worked out, so, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong??

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int arr[10][10];

int func(){
     //this function will be using the global arr
    // if(arr[x][y]!=-1)
          //do something
}

int main(){
//the code
}
```

Comment: Please don't use global variables.  They make spaghetti code and makes your program difficult to parse.  Give future you a break and write clean, maintainable code.

Comment: @NathanOliver okk so i will declare it inside the main function

Comment: @AnonymousUser -- After declaring it inside the function, try the `memset` again.

Comment: Side note: With the exception of variable initialization,  functions need to be called from within functions. `int x = function();` is valid. `x = function();` and just plain `function();` are not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i decided not to use it globally. So now i am doing that inside the main function .lol

Comment: @AnonymousUser -- I guess that was the point I was making when I mentioned to make it local.  You now see that the function call must be within the body of a function.  Whether it is a good function to use -- that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the good way to initialize a built-in array in place without code repetition. I do, however, know a way to initialize `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template<size_t... Ix>
auto constexpr make1array(int v, std::index_sequence<Ix...>) {
    auto populate = [](int v, size_t) { return v; };
    std::array<int, 10> a = { populate(v, Ix)... };
    return a;
}
template<size_t... Ix1, size_t... Ix2>
auto constexpr make2array(int v, std::index_sequence<Ix1...> seq, std::index_sequence<Ix2...>) {
    auto populate = [](auto v, size_t)  { return v; };
    std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> a = { populate(make1array(v, seq), Ix2)... };
    return a;
}

std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> arr = make2array(-1, std::make_index_sequence<10>{}, std::make_index_sequence<10>{});
```

This code produces an array pre-populated with `-1` as the value at compile time.

Comment: this just went from over my head. i am a beginner bro

Comment: Anything that works on std::array, can work on single dimensional raw array

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie - not here, though. There is a twist :)

Comment: @AnonymousUser That's actually a nice learning opportunity for some (semi)advanced  templating. It's not easy to come by a concise practical example which is quite clearly written. It is some effort to work through, especially hefty if you're beginner, but it's worth if you'll ever find it useful to be advanced in c++.

Answer (score 1):

The function `memset` won't work because `memset` uses bytes and many integers occupy more than one byte.

IMHO, your best source is to use `std::fill`.
Example:

```
std::fill(&arr[0][0], &arr[9][9] + 1, -1);
```

Otherwise, you can always fall back on the nested loop:

```
for (int r = 0; r < MAX_ROWS; ++r)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < MAX_COLUMNS; ++c)
    {
        arr[r][c] = -1;
    }
}
```

Your best bet is to let the compiler optimize the nested loops.

There may be some micro-optimizations that you could employ, but the compiler probably already has them in its tool chest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to initialize raw array by values that aren't result of default initialization. One of the reasons is that array cannot be returned from function and cannot be assigned directly from anything that is not a {}-list.

Simplest way (since C++14) is to make it part of  class-type with constexpr constructor. In C++111 constructor with non-empty body cannot be `constexpr`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MinusOneArray {
    static constexpr int NX =  10;
    static constexpr int NY =  10;
    int arr[NX][NY];
        
    constexpr MinusOneArray() : arr() {
        for(int i = 0; i < NX; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < NY; ++j)
                arr[i][j] = -1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MinusOneArray a;
    auto &arr = a.arr;
    
    for(auto &line: arr) {
        for(auto val: line)
            std::cout << val << ",";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Alternative is to use standard structure `std::array` and initialize it with constexpr function, how SergeyA offered.